# excluding multiple message using MSG_EXCEPT at once in msgrcv()

Tags: linux, multithreading, ipc, msgrcv

I am using msgrcv() to read messages from a queue. There are multiple threads, each handling its own message type from a common queue.
Lets say there are 3 threads handling message type A, B and C respectively as below:
`

```
thread1()
{
    msg_t msg;
    while(1)
    {
        msgrcv(qid, msg, sizeof(msg), A, 0)
        .
        .
    }
}
.
.
thread2()
{
    msg_t msg;
    while(1)
    {
        msgrcv(qid, msg, sizeof(msg), B, 0)
        .
        .
    }
}
.
.
thread3()
{
    msg_t msg;
    while(1)
    {
        msgrcv(qid, msg, sizeof(msg), C, 0)
        .
        .
    }
}
```

`

Now I want a fourth thread that can receive all the messages except these three.
Can it be achieved using MSG_EXCEPT flag?

Thanks.

I dont know how to use 'MSG_EXCEPT' flag to exclude multiple message types at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it be achieved using MSG_EXCEPT flag?

No, it can't. Instead, provided that you can arrange A, B and C to be greater than all other used message types, you can achieve the goal by specifying the negative of a *msgtyp* less than A, B and C.

Comment: The actual issue I am facing is that I sometimes see a large number of bytes in the queue (checked using **msqid_ds** structure)whenever a message(either A, B, or C) is sent and neither of the three threads fetches the message from the queue. So I am doubting that somehow the message is corrupted and the message type of the new message is different from A, B, and C. All three threads are stuck on msgrcv() function.

Comment: The **msqid_ds** logs each time I send a message are as:

Number of bytes in queue: 5281
Maximum number of bytes in queue: 16384
Number of msgs in queue: 1

Number of bytes in queue: 10561
Maximum number of bytes in queue: 16384
Number of msgs in queue: 2

Comment: What you write doesn't preclude the option to choose the three highest possible integers for A, B and C and to then receive all other messages with the negative of a _msgtyp_ one less.